# Bigquery | Result of ORDER BY queries cannot be partitioned by field

Tags: airflow, bq

I am using Bigquery Operator for my Airflow Task. I am passing an Sql query to operator and trying to insert result of BQ query into a BQ table. While doing this, getting below error

**google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Result of ORDER BY queries cannot be partitioned by field 'batch_date'**

Same SQL query works fine if run on BQ console. Table is partitioned on batch_date so the table name I am passing to BQ operator is ***table_name$batch_date***

This error is coming for BQ insert job.

Any help/clue?

Answer (score 4):

Simply remove the ORDER BY clause in the main query and it works

Comment: Thanks Danny.. It does work without ORDER BY clause. But I need that clause and to my surprise It was working till couple of days back with ORDER BY clause.. started failing since yesterday..Any other alternative which works even with ORDER BY clause?

Comment: I met the same problem exactly like yours. But for my case as it serves as a raw table for further processing so this solution works for me.

Comment: Do we know why this error happens? Seems like ORDER BY should be working for a valid field.

Answer (score 0):

Because If the table creator
CREATE TABLE with
PARTITION BY
batch_date
is added to the CREATE TABLE.